# PiCamera motion array structure

Tags: camera, motion

From the following:

http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_array.html?highlight=sad[1]

In PiMotionAnalysis, "The data-type of the array is an (x, y, sad) structure where x and y are signed 1-byte values, and sad is an unsigned 2-byte value representing the sum of absolute differences of the block."
What does x and y represent?

Comment: I believe it is the x and y value of the macro block (row and column) counting left and down from the top left.

Comment: Why signed then? And I do get positive and negative values. The example of PiMotionAnalysis uses the sqrt of the sum of squares of x and y. I'm puzzled because I would use only sad as the difference between each frame, why x and y before? What do they represent? I only have questions...

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have cracked it! Oh what good 3 hours of sleep do to us.

x and y may be the displacement vector of a given macroblock in his coordinate. I found this because when printing a['x'] and moving a sheet of paper along the camera x axis in one direction showed a matrix with mostly positive values and when moving to the other direction the signs changed.

I think I can work with this.

Comment: Oh dear! My apologies - I didn't write that piece of documentation very well - I'll revisit it before the next release!

Comment: And just to confirm, yes it is indeed the vector displacement

Comment: Thank you! I'm having a lot of fun swiping in front of the camera and getting commands executed while recording. It's amazing what the Pi is capable of.

Comment: Have a look [at these](https://gist.github.com/waveform80/40d803aa31485f94cd53) for some more ideas of playing with the analysis classes (I'm intending to get them into the docs for the next release when I get a spare second, but those are becoming extremely rare at the moment!)

Comment: Will check them in detail this week, I'm very grateful.